# What is the name of this form control in Windows Forms (Visual Studio)?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

Im looking for the name of this **form control of Windows Forms**, Visual Studio, do anyone know the name? I have many controls like text boxes in a form but the form is not big so I want to put them inside this form control to reduce space.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to [`Panel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)?

Comment: [PropertyGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) maybe?

Comment: @Filburt yes, it's that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control shown in your picture is [PropertyGride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?view=windowsdesktop-8.0).